# Can merge-request be merged - custom check in GitLab

Tags: gitlab

To enforce some policies before a merge request (MR) is merged I added a server side update hook - which is only executed when merging against develop.

This works as it should - but the problem is you only get the feedback after you accept the merge request.

What we want is some kind of preflight check - this MR can be merged. (Like GitLab itself does when it checks if the MR doesn't produce a conflict).

Is there any way to hook into this system?

### Edit

Added image for better understanding:

[image]

Comment: You can add jobs in CI and disallow merge if a job fails. But jobs fire for each push, not for merge requests.

Comment: im aware of that, and we use a lot of jobs for our builds and deployment.
its a developer thing, the dont like to have red builds. so the tend to squash every commit.

Comment: Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/gitlab/articles/69193717/how-to-use-external-status-checks-for-merge-requests helps.

Comment: Yes today this is possible - it wasn't in 2017 :)